# But why? - Enterprise Territory Management cannot be enabled in existing organizations that have Customizable Forecasting enabled

Tags: territory-management, forecast, territory

Is there a deep underlying logic?

They say, 
1. Standard Fiscal year goes with Standard forecasting
2. Custom Fiscal year with customizable forecasting and with Territory mgmt 1.0
3. Custom Fiscal year with Collaborative forecasting and with Territory mgmt 2.0

But why??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix and match Forecasting and Territory Management versions. You have to back out customizable and use collaborative in order to use the new territory management...not that that would be a trivial effort but that is what we were told by support last year. You can check out the guide that explicitly states this: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_implementing_territory_mgmt2_guide.pdf

This is the old Territory Management help page: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_def.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Eric, thanks for the comment but you are re-iterating the fact. My question really is - why cant we mix and match?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. You can open a ticket with Salesforce but I doubt the answer will change. We went through this Support last year and that's the answer we got.

Comment: No problem, I am unsure what is the limitation for.

Comment: Salesforce itself is confused. The link shared by @EricClay tells that Territory Management can only be combined with Collaborative Forecasts, whereas https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_forecasts3_whats_difference_between_versions.htm&language=en_US states that it can only be combined with Customizable Forecasts. I think they mean Collaborative, since that is the newest way of Forecasting.